# Como crear una macro para desplazar una formula a la siguiente columna

Tags: excel, vba, macros

Necesito crear una macro para poder desplazar una formula (ejemplo: J7-(TG7+TH7)) a la siguiente columna (ejemplo: J7-(TH7+TI7))
¿Me podría ayudar alguien?

Muchas gracias!
Saludos

Comment: Bienvenido a SO en español. No necesitas una macro para eso, puedes arrastrar manualmente jugando con referencias relativas y absolutas. Aun así, si necesitas una macro, tienes que poner el código que has desarrollado y qué parte te da error. Por favor, lee [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) y no olvides leer [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Visita también el  [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)